# How to get an editor for a column in AutoFilterRow (devexpress xtragridview)?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am using XtraGrid control, with GridView. I have AutoFilterRow enabled.

For text columns, I do a LIKE search, and for a dropdown column, I assigned ColumnEdit = ReositoryItemComboBox.

It appears for this column in all the rows except the AutoFilterRow. How to get it in AutoFilterRow as well ?

Answer (score 1):

To display the editor for the auto filer row, handle the [CustomRowCellEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomRowCellEdittopic) event as shown below:

```
void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) {
    GridView view = sender as GridView;
    if(e.Column.FieldName == "COMM_TYPE" && view.IsFilterRow(e.RowHandle))
        e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox1;
}
```

Comment: basically this will be called on each and every cell edit. will try it though. thanks. isnt there any other efficient solution, able to set it once at start or something

Comment: This solution as efficient as possible. It is not a problem that this will be called on every cell edit. How many cell edits can you perform per second?

Comment: You can also yse the [RepositoryItemImageComboboxEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemImageComboBoxtopic) that allows values from an enumeration to be automaticaly displayed within the auto-filter row